# Cypress Before hook executing multiple times per test?

Tags: for-loop, testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm doing some e2e testing with cypress and ran into an issue with before hooks. I am testing multiple pages with the same test but different variables. As such i have wrapped my tests within a function so that i can loop over the function for every test i need to run. At the top of my function i have a before hook which should execute once before all tests in the function, but instead it executes for each iteration of the function. I.e running my function 10 times causes the before hook to run 10 times every time i run my function.

Here is an MRE which is structured in the same way im running my tests:

```
function runTests(index) {

    before(() => {
        cy.visit('https://google.com')
    })

    describe('Tests some stuff', () => {
        describe(('Tests some stuff'), () => {
            it('Tests some stuff', () => {
                cy.log(index)
            })
        })

    })
}
  
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  runTests(i)
}
```

I am expecting this to visit google once before each test and then print out the current iteration of the function. Instead it is visiting google 10 times before printing the iteration.

Comment: You can simply move the before outside of your function and for loop.

Comment: @jjhelguero Correct thanks! Just had to restructure my code so that my before hook wasn't dependent on the parent function.